# How to share a Value between apps on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

is it possible to share a value in keychain that any app can use?
in my iPhone app i want to share an information(value) that anyone can use, with different bundle identifier apps also. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you just looking for different bundle identifiers or different App ID's?  Keychain is tied to App ID, but the clipboard is available across ID's.

Answer (score 3):

Your apps need to use the same app-id prefix. [Checkout the keychain example.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html)
Otherwise, no you can't share data between apps with different prefixes. The best you could do is post the data to a publicly available API.

Answer (score 2):

`handleOpenURL` will do the trick

Sender application

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"appA://localhost/exportedData/base64Data"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Receiver application

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

This [link](http://kotikan.com/blog/posts/2011/03/passing-data-between-ios-apps) will help you out.

Comment: It is noteworthy that this will not only pass the data to said receiver application, but it will also launch that application right away

Answer (score 1):

All apps that share the same bundle id can access a shared keychain if permission has been granted in your Entitlements.plist file.

Otherwise no.